# WordPress rest route error 404 "code": "rest_no_route",

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

```
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_api_hooks');
    function register_api_hooks(){
    register_rest_route('users/v1','/upload_archieve',
array('methods' => 'POST','callback' =>'Upload_archive_file'));
    register_rest_route('users/v1','/get_archive',
array('methods' => 'GET','callback' => 'get_archive_files'));
    }

    function get_archive_files($r){
    return $r['user_id'];
    }

    function Upload_archive_file($r){
    return upload_file($_FILE['attachment']);
    }
```

It was working well for POST and GET methods.

now, POST methods is returning ->
`{ "code": "rest_no_route", "message": "A path that matches the URL and request method was not found.", "data": { "status": 404 } }`

and GET method is working perfect.

- I tried to change method string from "POST" to 'post' and opposite.
- Refresh htaccess file by permalink settings.
- Change the endpoint and try again.

Hope anyone here have a knowledge what is the problem that may cause this.

And Thanks at all.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having a similar issue, interestingly when I change my resource path, for example from /phrase to /phrases and retest, boom, we're working again but not when I revert back. I'm thinking some cache mechanism, maybe yours is similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the typo now, in your first `register_rest_route call`, the second argument for the route resource path, you have `'/upload_archieve'` instead of `'/upload_archive'`.